# How do I find a shutter-style (off-half-full press) momentary button?

Tags: switches, components

I'm looking for a momentary button that has three positions, like a camera, so you can momentary-press halfway or momentary-press the full depth.

I don't even know what to call it, so searching 41,000 switches on Mouser doesn't help. If I can't find it I can mimic it in software, but I'd prefer to have the camera-style tactile response

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I believe the search term you need is "double action".

Example https://www.ckswitches.com/media/1897/kxt2.pdf

[image]

Comment: thanks! I just couldn't find it without the precise word.